# Uniqueness continuation property for parabolic equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, uniqueness-theorems

Consider the following parabolic equation:
$$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{\partial \rho }{\partial t}-\Div\left( a\left( x\right) \nabla
\rho \right) +p(x)\rho  =  0 &  \text{in } 
Q, \\ 
\rho \left( 0\right)  =  \rho ^{\circ } & \text{in } \Omega , \\ 
\rho  =  0 & \text{on }  \Sigma,
\end{cases}
$$
where $Q=\Omega \times(0,T)$ and $\Sigma=\Gamma \times(0,T)$.

We want to prove the following implication:
$$
\dfrac{\partial \rho}{\partial \eta _{a}}=a\left( x\right) \nabla \rho\cdot\eta=0 
$$ on $\omega \times(0,T) \Longrightarrow \rho^{\circ } =0$ in $\Omega$ where

- $a(x)\in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$,
- $\alpha_0\leq a(x) \leq \alpha_1$ a.e. in $\bar{\Omega}$ for $\alpha_0, \alpha_1>0$, and
- $\omega \subset \Omega$.

**Question**: how can I prove this implication? Or can I find any references which cite/give a proof of the above implication?

Comment: What is $\eta$?

Comment: It's the unit normal vector.